# What's the best Cocoa class to use for detecting double-clicks?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm creating an interface programmatically that contains a grid of cells. I'd like the user to be able to click a cell once to "select" it and double click it to activate it (shouldn't have to be selected). I'm wondering if there's an existing class that I should be using to support this sort of functionality or if I should just use an `NSButton` and muck around with event handling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a grid of cells, you'll want NSMatrix, which has a `doubleAction` property that holds the selector for a double-click action.

Comment: Your answer was perfect! NSMatrix has -setDoubleAction http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMatrix_Class/Reference/Reference.html